# Unexpected error while getting the method or property moveTo on object DriveApp.File

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have this code to export a students' list from sheets to make each students his own docs file under a specific folder (There is also a shared file between all students in this folder which is created and shared beforehand).
for some reason moving the new specific student documents to the folder throws an error
Here's the script:

```
function createBase() { //Shared Folder and file
  if (DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Shared Folder").hasNext() == true)
  {}
  else 
  {
    var folder = DriveApp.createFolder ("Shared Folder");
    var title = 'Test';    
    var doc = DocumentApp.create(title);
    maindocFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
    maindocFile.moveTo(folder);
  }
  var mainDoc = folder;
  return mainDoc;
}

function userFiles() {
  var id = "idString"; //Changed for privacy reasons
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Students");
  var numrows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getNumRows();
  for (var i = 2; i<= numrows; i++) //Run a for loop on the students' list and get each name & email, and make a doc with it 
  {
    var userName = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue().toString();
    var email = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue().toString();
    if (DriveApp.getFilesByName("Specific Doc - "+ userName).hasNext() == true) //Checking if the doc exists
    {}
    else { //Else - create the doc.. DUH!
      var doc = DocumentApp.create("Specific Doc - "+ userName);
      docFile = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
      docFile.moveTo(createBase()); //Check what is wrong here
      var docId = doc.getId();
      var customMessage = "This is your own document!";  // set a new custom message.
      var resource = {role: "writer", type: "user", value: email};
      Drive.Permissions.insert(resource, docId, {emailMessage: customMessage}); //Permission access   
      var maindocId = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Test');
      var resource2 = {role: "reader", type: "user", value: email};
      var maincustomMessage = "This is our main document"; 
      //Custom message for your main shared document
      Drive.Permissions.insert(resource2, maindocId, {emailMessage: maincustomMessage}); //Permission access
      
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: createBase() returns undefined. If the first condition is met (you already have existing folder called 'Shared Folder'), the 'else' condition is never executed. Which makes both 'folder' and 'mainDoc' variables undefined.

Comment: @AntonDementiev right my bad, but when I'm adding the moveTo line in the first condition, I don't have access to DriveApp.Folder, I can receive a FileIterator instead but it doesn't really helpful for writing a destination  in moveTo()

Comment: The getFolderByName() method returns a FolderIterator with a built-in next() method that you can use to traverse the list of folders. let iterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("YOUR_FOLDER"). If (iterator.hasNext()) { let folder = iterator.next(); }.   When in doubt, please refer to Apps Script docs, they have every single method explained and documented so you don't have to guess https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - (Also thanks to Anton who commented)
in the 1st if in createBase(), you have to add this code:

```
var mainDoc = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('Shared Folder').next();
return mainDoc;
```

it was my bad that I didn't mention anything in these if brackets, but the main issue was returning DriveApp.folder and not folderIterator, You can do it by using .next()